# Why is 1 added?

Tags: typescript, date, math

I got this code from https://gist.github.com/vincentorback/8edffeca20e7a9e5e2a6 and was wondering a couple things about it.

```js
/**
 * Gets the ISO week number for a given date.
 * @param d either Date or number, the date to get week number for.
 * @returns The ISO week number for given date.
 */
function getWeekNumber(d: any) {
    // copy given date
    d = new Date(+d);
    d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    // Set date to nearest thursday
    // If getDay is 0 it's sunday, we change the day number to 7 making it the last day of the week
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4 - (d.getDay() || 7));
    const yearStart: any = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
    // First calculate delta of start of year and given date in milliseconds: (d - yearStart)
    // Then we divide that by 86.400.000 ((d - yearStart) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 ) to know difference in days
    // Then we calculate the number of weeks
    return Math.ceil((((d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1) / 7); // <-- why + 1?
}
```

I don't really get why `+ 1` is done there. And also why is the day number changed to 7 when it's sunday?

I tried commenting about the things I did figure out but if it's still unclear let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Set date to nearest thursday
// If getDay is 0 it's sunday, we change the day number to 7 making it the last day of the week
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4 - (d.getDay() || 7));
```

At this stage, `d` is a pure date. There are exactly 7 possible valuse for `d.getDay()`, corresponding to the day of the week: `0` for Sunday, `1` for Monday, and so on.

As the comment notes, the `|| 7` means that we now have `1` for Monday, ..., `7` for Sunday.

For any date, if we subtract its day-of-week number (in this system), we get the Sunday before it (try it!). For example, today is Tuesday 5th November 2019. Day-of-week number is 2. Today minus 2 days is the Sunday before today.

Then we add 4, which will mean we're on a Thursday as desired. This is the 'nearest' Thursday because of the 0 -> 7 mapping. Without the mapping of 0 to 7 for Sunday, Sunday 3rd November 2019 would end up as Thursday 7th; *with* that mapping, it ends up as thursday 31st October, which is nearer.

---

```
// First calculate delta of start of year and given date in milliseconds: (d - yearStart)
// Then we divide that by 86.400.000 ((d - yearStart) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 ) to know difference in days
// Then we calculate the number of weeks
return Math.ceil((((d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1) / 7); // <-- why + 1?
```

At this point `d` is a pure-date Thursday, and `yearStart` is Jan 1st of the same year.

Subtracting a date from a date gives us the difference *in milliseconds*. There are 86400000 milliseconds in a day, so dividing the daet-subtraction value by 86400000 gives us the difference in days.

So `((d - yearStart) / 86400000)` is the day-of-year, starting at `0` for Jan 1st.

We want to get a week-of-year value, so we divide by 7, which will give us a non-integer most of the time, but we want an integer so we take the ceiling (ie we round up).

However, that would mean that Jan 1st (which is day-of-year 0) would end up as the only day to be in week 0. Apparently we don't want this so we add 1 to our day-of-year.

So `(((d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1)` is the day-of-year, starting at **`1`** for Jan 1st.

We now have the numbers 1 through 365 (or 366) for the days of the year; divide by 7 and round up to get the numbers 1 through 53, for the weeks of the year.